# Test strict equality (case sensitive) codeigniter->mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Hello I would like to verify user credentials:

- Login (no case sensitive),
- Password (case sensitive).

How can i do this with Codeigniter 3 please?

```
$this->db->where('username', $username);  
$this->db->where('password', $password);
```

Comment: You should NEVER store passwords in plaintext like that!!! Store the password hashed, then when you want to log in, fetch the hashed password and compare against it in PHP (with functions such as `password_hash()`/`password_verify()`).

Comment: Yes sure, this is for the exemple

Comment: Yes, you need to hash passwords and then store them and use `password_verify()` php function to check their correctness. For username(of course filtered) , it could be stored like `$username = strtolower($username);`, so you won't need an additional check of `LCASE()` with MySQL to be checked against each row.

Comment: The passward is just an exemple, I will need to check the case in several situations

Comment: You could check against its binaries, but you seriously should reconsider if you're using this for passwords. Its not safe to not hash passwords (and by hashing them, they become case-sensitive).